# Making a bivariate map with separated variables in the legend

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am currently making a bivariate map and I would like to know if it's possible to have for the legend part of the map the two variables used in two clear separate legend form next to the fused legend using both variables.

Basically I want to show the exact same thing as what's on the picture and have these 3 elements show in the legend fields

[image]

Comment: No is the short answer.